# Reinterpret bytes as float in C (IEEE 754 single-precision binary)

Tags: c, floating-point, byte, code-composer, single-precision

I want to reinterpret 4 bytes as IEEE 754 single-precision binary in C.

To obtain the bytes that represent `float`, I used:

```
num = *(uint32_t*)&MyFloatNumber;
aux[0] = num  & 0xFF;
aux[1] = (num >> 8) & 0xFF;
aux[2] = (num >> 16)  & 0xFF;
aux[3] = (num >> 24)  & 0xFF;
```

- num is a uint32_t.
- aux[] is int[4].

To reinterpret the bytes as a `float`, I’m trying:

```
Buff = *(float*)&aux;
```

In that second case nothing apears on "Buff"

- Buff is a `float`.

What am I doing wrong in the second case?

Comment: You have not reversed the original (dubious) conversion.

Comment: Hmmm `aux[]` is`int[4];` and code is using that to `convert BYTE to FLOAT`??

Comment: Is this the [XY problem?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)?

Comment: `aux` should probably be a `char[4]` or `uint8_t[4]`

Comment: Neither of these conversions does a useful thing--I suspect you actually do have some meaningful conversion in mind, but I can't decipher it from this question. So what are you actually trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 3):

2 problems:

1. `Buff = *(float*)&aux;` attempts to use the address of an array of 4 `int` as a pointer to a float.  `aux[]` is perhaps 16 bytes long and a *IEEE 754 single-precision binary* `float` is expected to be 4 bytes.
2. Both casts: `(uint32_t*)` and `(float*)` invoke *undefined behavior* as well as alignment and anti-aliasing issues.  Better to use a `union`.

   ```
   int main(void) {
     union {
       float f;
       unsigned char uc[sizeof(float)];
     } x;

     // float to bytes
     x.f = 1.23f;
     printf("%x %x %x %x\n", x.uc[0], x.uc[1], x.uc[2], x.uc[3]);

     // bytes to float
     x.uc[0] = 0xA4;
     x.uc[1] = 0x70;
     x.uc[2] = 0x9D;
     x.uc[3] = 0x3F;
     printf("%.8e\n", x.f);
   }
   ```

Output

```
a4 70 9d 3f
1.23000002e+00
```

Comment: I'm using a microcontroller that does not allow the use of the printf function, you would have another way to do the conversion (bytes to float)?

Comment: @Guilherme Even without `printf("%.8e\n", x.f);`, the converted `float` is in `x.f`.  `printf("%.8e\n", x.f);` is only for display purposes.